# Is the interval topology of $(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}, \leq^*)$ connected?

Tags: gn.general-topology, order-theory

Given a quasi-ordered set $(Q,\leq)$ the *interval topology* on $Q$ is generated by
$$\{Q\setminus\downarrow x : x\in Q\} \cup \{Q\setminus\uparrow x : x\in Q\},$$
where $\downarrow x = \{y\in Q: y\leq x\}$ and $\uparrow x = \{y\in Q: y\geq x\}$.

Let $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ and define a quasi-ordering relation $\leq^*$ on $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ by $$f\leq^* g \text{ iff } \exists k\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } f(n) \leq g(n) \text{ for all } n\geq k.$$

Let $\tau_i(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N})$ be the interval topology of $(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}, \leq^*)$.

Is $(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}, \tau_i(\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}))$ connected?

Comment: Does it has the stronger property that any two nonempty open sets has nonempty intersection?

Comment: Good question @FanZheng - I don't know...!

Comment: @FanZheng What sequence could belong both to the open set of sequences which are eventually less than the constant 1 sequence and to the open set of sequences which are eventually greater than the constant 2 sequence?

Comment: @ToddTrimble If I didn't get it wrong, the open set is defined as the set of sequences *not* eventually less/greater than a given sequence. So this is a very weak topology, which suggested my question above.

Comment: Read "any of finitely many given sequences" for "a given sequence" above.

Comment: @FanZheng Might we have different ideas as to how the interval topology is defined? I was thinking $(y, z)$ means the set of $x$ such that $y < x < z$ where $y < x$ means $y \leq x$ and $y \neq x$. Maybe I have misunderstood, but it looks like you are using $x \not\le y$ and $z \not\le x$, which looks to me like something different.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I'm defining it as per the OP. But for completeness I will also answer the question using your definition, whose answer is the other way round.

Comment: @FanZheng Oh, indeed you are!  My apologies then.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen I also answered your other question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/226639/interval-topology-on-mathbbn-mathbbn-leq/226800#226800. If that's what you want, please accept them, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim that this topology has the stronger property of being [hyperconnected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space), i.e., the intersection of any two nonempty open sets is nonempty.

Indeed, any open set contains a set of the form

$$ U=\bigcap_{i=1}^m \{x:x\not\le^*y_i\}\bigcap\bigcap_{j=1}^n \{x:x\not\ge^*z_j\} $$

so the same can be said of the intersection of two open sets. I claim that

> $U$ is nonempty iff every $z_j$ has infinitely many nonzero terms.

It is easy to see this claim implies that the topology is hyperconnected. Now we show the claim.

Clearly this condition is necessary, for if $z_j$ has finitely many nonzero terms, then for every $x\in\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ we have $x\ge^*z_j$. Conversely, assume all of $z_j$ has infinitely many nonzero terms, then we can produce an $x\in U$ by the following algorithm:

`x=0 //initialize x to the zero array
k=0 //k indexes x
while true do
  for i = 1 to m
    x(k)=y(i)(k)+1 //Repeating this infinitely makes x\not\le^*y_i
    k=k+1
  end for
  for j = 1 to n
    while z(j)(k)=0 do
      k=k+1
    end while //This loop must end because z(j) has infinitely many nonzero terms
    x(k)=0 //Repeating this infinitely makes x\not\ge^*z_j as z(j)(k)>0
  end for
end while`

**Edit**: As Todd noted in the comment, another natural definition of the interval topology is generated by the open sets $\{x:x^*>y\}$ and $\{x:x^*<z\}$, where $x<^*y$ iff there is $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $x_n<y_n$.

This topology is very different from the previous one. In fact it is *not* connected. It can be written as $U\cup V$, where $U$ is the set of all sequences tending to $+\infty$ and $V$ is its complement. We will show that both $U$ and $V$ are open.

Take $x\in U$. Then there is $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $x_n>0$. Let

$$ y_n=\begin{cases}x_n & n\le n_0\\ x_n-1 & n>n_0 \end{cases}. $$

Then $y\in U$ and $x\in (y,+\infty)\subset U$.

Take $x\in V$. Let $z=x+1$ (termwise). Then $z\in V$ and $x\in (-\infty,z)\subset V$.